# Git CRLF for windows users

Tags: windows, git, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

I know that there are tons of articles about this issue. But I'm struggling with it for couple of weeks with no success.

I'm trying to use best practices that are discribed on [github](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings). So I added a .gitattributes file, for example it looks like this:

```
*.cs text
```

And I've normalized line endings for all files. Now I have clean working copy with nothing to commit. But now if I open a fine in any windows text editor and make some random change, save file, undo that change I see this file as changed. I understand that this is because file now has windows style line endings. But this is horrible way of working, file has no changes and I want git to know about it without `git reset --hard`. What would you recommend in such case?

Comment: How actually you "normalized" it? For windows I use `\r\n` in my `.cs` files and use `as-is` line endings git setting

Comment: What is telling you that the file has changed. Have you tried running `git status` to refresh the cache?

Comment: Yes git status is telling that file has changed.

Comment: @zerkms I've removed all files with git rm --cached . and made git reset --hard to force all files to be modified by git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want the eol style of your files changed back to windows, don't ask git to perform any "automagic" transformation.
So, contrary to the "[best practices from GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)":

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

If you really (I mean *really*) need one specific set of files in one specific directory to get a particular eol style, add it in your [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) within said directory, meaning **not using `text=auto`**, only "`text eol=lf or crlf`"

Comment: Some more reference: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Comment: So you mean setting *.cs -text=auto int gitattributes in order to override core.autocrlf setting?

Comment: @Sly if the `core.autocrlf` is set to false, you don't need to use `auto` ever. only `lf`or `crlf` if you want to enforce a particular style. Or nothing, if your text editor doesn't change the eol when saving a file.

Answer (score 3):

The real question here is: what are you working on and with whom?

Unless you are doing OSS work, all this attribute confusion is not worth it. For an organization with a team of people, turn automatic line ending conversions off by setting:

```
core.autocrlf false
```

This covers the majority of cases out there.

If you have a submodule that is on GitHub, you can set those up on a per repo basis.